# Excel - Cell Values at Interval

Tags: excel, intervals

I have the following scenario:

If cell I2 has a value, I want cell I3 to be equal to D3 and continue until 2 years (=C3), then next 2 years (=E3-C3) as $1 (=F3), then next 2 years (=G3-E3) as $3 (=H3).

I want the following as shown below in I3 to T3. How to do this in excel?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Why does it repeat after 2024?

Comment: because there is a cell value at O2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand the purpose of triggering a reset of the phase costs so I won't include that in my answer until you review your question to properly explain it. Otherwise, see my answer below.

I would think a separate table is more concise for display values and lets you extend easier without adding columns.

I changed from year number (1-6) to year (2019-2024) since that's what you are displaying. I then used an INDEX MATCH but used the lookup argument of `1` to allow matching values greater than the year start.

[image: excel snip]

EDIT

In order to do what you would like, I had to set a start and end range on the left side. Please recreate the formulas in your workbook.

[image]